# How to change password of AWS Cognito User?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, passwords, amazon-cognito

I'm developing a web application which uses the AWS services backend side.
I'm using AWS Cognito to manage the users but I have a problem. When I create a new user (with a temporary password) it is required that I change this password manually to make it definitive.
The only way I have to change the password is using AWS Cli, as explained here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/change-password.html

I have to type in the shell the old password, the new password and the Access Token. The problem is: where I find this "Access token"? I don't know what to type in the shell! The AWS Cognito console doen't help.

Comment: On a related note - there is now the ability for admin to set a permanent password. Yay! https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html

Answer (score 54):

To change a user password :

With this aws cli :

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.17.9 Python/3.6.10 Linux/5.3.0-26-generic botocore/1.14.9
```

You can do this this way :

```
aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-password --user-pool-id "eu-west-11111"  --username "aaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa" --password "a new password" --permanent
```

To have more information :

```
 aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-password help
```

Comment: There is NO admin-set-user-password. As per the documentation, there is admin-reset-user-password and that will send a verification code to the mail id specified

Comment: As at May 2020, there is an admin-set-user-password: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-set-user-password.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Hettomei. I was able to execute this command from the CloudShell successfully.

Comment: You may need to add the region flag `--region xx-xxxx-xx` if you're targeting a user pool that's not on the set default region.

Comment: I had to use single quotes to enclose the new password as my MacOS did not like the bang in double quotes.  Thanks for posting this info @Hettomei!

Answer (score 31):

The `aws cognito-idp change-password` can only be used with a user who is able to sign in, because you need the Access token from `aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth`.

But since the user has a temporary password, it will face the `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` challenge when trying to sign in.

Here's how I did it:

```
$ aws cognito-idp admin-create-user  --user-pool-id USERPOOLID  --username me@example.com --desired-delivery-mediums EMAIL --user-attributes Name=email,Value=me@example.com

$ aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --client-id CLIENTID --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=me@example.com.me,PASSWORD="tempPassword"
```

Now you get a `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` challenge and a very long session token.
Use that one to respond to the challenge:

```
$ aws cognito-idp admin-respond-to-auth-challenge --user-pool-id USERPOOLID --client-id CLIENTID   --challenge-responses "NEW_PASSWORD=LaLaLaLa1234!!!!,USERNAME=me@example.com" --challenge-name NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED --session "YourLongSessionToken"
```

**Update:**

Since the original answer, a new option, `aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-password` has been introduced.

Comment: Where do you get the CLIENTID value when executing the `aws cognito-idp initiate-auth ...`?

Comment: You simply create a client in the AWS Cognito configuration (either using console, CLI or CloudFormation).

That client ID is also used as a configuration variable in the app/website that's logging in to Cognito.

Comment: I don't see USER_PASSWORD_AUTH as an option for --auth-flow when I type in ```aws cognito-idp initiate-user help```. I'm unsure of what the alternative would be or if I have my setup improperly configured.

Comment: @MatthewZackschewski Looks like you are calling `initiate-user`, not `initiate-auth` :)

Comment: @EsbenvonBuchwald Duh... thanks. Been a long day :)

Answer (score 4):

The right API is:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html

The syntax is:

```
{
   "Password": "string",
   "Permanent": true,
   "Username": "string",
   "UserPoolId": "string"
}
```

You can specify that the specified password is permanent, and you will have the user in the CONFIRMED status.
It's correct that this API doesn't require the old password, because it wouldn't be safe. The admin doesn't need to know user passwords. So the API has been named "AdminSetUserPassword" and not "AdminChangeUserPassword".

Answer (score 0):

The access token is retrieved by logging the user in. You can get this token by running the aws cli command `aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth` for the user (Found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-initiate-auth.html)).

This will require you to have root credentials for the cognito pool, which I assume you have. The command will return the access token which you can use for one hour (cognito tokens expire after 1 hour regardless of settings, look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)).

Comment: You only get the access token afte a successful login, not when you hit a challenge.